# Prevent empty string on query if viewing root

Tags: php

I use the following for getting the current URL in PHP:

```
$pageURL = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

return $pageURL;
```

This is used in my links to create e.g `/login?continue=/page/i/want`

However when I'm viewing the home page I will get `/login?continue=` how do I force it to become `/login?continue=/` when viewing the home page??

I tried this:

```
if($pageURL == '')
    $pageURL = '/';
```

but that didn't force the query string :/

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `$pageURL += '/'`?

Comment: do you want to change what the URL looks like to the user, or does it affect the server somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, it will work only if the url has one **"="** only:

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$arr = explode("=", $url);
if(empty($arr[1])) {
   $url .="/";
}
echo $url;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I ended up just wrapping the link in an if statement that if it was the home page then don't append the continue query string. A little sloppy but means that I don't have the query string at all if their isn't anywhere to redirect to.